# what would be the appropriate buffer size passed to the SSL_read() call on the reciever side for best performance?

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography

I am writing Client Server application using Openssl and using TLS protocol for the communication.

In my server, it sends variable length of messages ranging from 100 bytes to 30 Kbytes sized messages to the Client.

In the Client program I am using non-blocking sockets to implement Openssl TLS recieving.

My question is, what should be the appropriate buffer size I should pass to the SSL_read() call for the best performance?

If I set the recieving buffer at 100 bytes, will it not cause too many read() system calls made by the SSL_read() on the socket even to construct the record and then return me the actual message, in case of server sends a 32KB message?

or

SSL-read() does read() system calls with different buffer sizes then what I pass to the SSL_read() call. If so, where can I find the documentation on how SSL_read() optimizes the process?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the documentation for [`SSL_read`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_read.html) and [`SSL_pending`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_pending.html) you'll find a lot of information. Among which:

> *SSL_read*:
> The read functions work based on the SSL/TLS records. The data are
> received in records (with a maximum record size of **16kB**). Only when a
> record has been completely received, can it be processed (decryption
> and check of integrity). Therefore, data that was not retrieved at the
> last read call can still be buffered inside the SSL layer and will be
> retrieved on the next read call.

Which tells you that OpenSSL is doing plenty of things in the background and the data you get at `SSL_read` may not even be the data it read from the socket. Moreover you may not even get any data at all from OpenSSL even though it did get data from the socket:

> *SSL_pending*:
> Therefore, it is possible for no more bytes to be readable from the
> underlying BIO (because OpenSSL has already read them) and for
> SSL_pending() to return 0, even though readable application data bytes
> are available (because the data is in unprocessed buffered records).
>
> *SSL_read*:
> If the underlying BIO is blocking, a read function will only return once the read operation has been finished or an error occurred, except when a non-application data record has been processed and SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY is not set.
> *(...)*
> If the underlying BIO is nonblocking, a read function will also return when the underlying BIO could not satisfy the needs of the function to continue the operation.

Perhaps more importantly for your question:

> *SSL_read*:
> If num *(the read size parameter)* is higher than the number of bytes buffered then the read functions will return with the bytes buffered. If no more bytes are in the buffer, the read functions will trigger the processing of the next record. Only when the record has been **received and processed** completely will the read functions return reporting success. **At most the contents of one record will be returned.** As the size of an SSL/TLS record may exceed the maximum packet size of the underlying transport (e.g. TCP), **it may be necessary to read several packets from the transport layer before the record is complete and the read call can succeed**.

There are a few more paragraphs of interest in SSL_pending (regarding `SSL_CTX_set_read_ahead` and `SSL_CTX_set_split_send_fragment`), but really I'd advise reading both the SSL_send and SSL_pending pages fully.

Hopefully I could make it clear that you can't really control how/when OpenSSL chooses to read from the socket. You calling SSL_read will only cause socket reads when necessary. Even if your buffer is very small, OpenSSL will just wait until you've flushed out enough data from it's internal output buffers. Then it'll process any queued unprocessed data and put that in the internal output buffers so again you can read it out. And only once it feels there's no more data backed up will a call to SSL_read result in a socket read.

In essence, from your end it seems it's not particularly important.. no matter the buffer size, it's a memory copy from OpenSSL buffers, not implicitly a syscall.
By default you'll be reading no more than a single record (≤16kB), so if you were using a lot of data, I would maybe advise allocating a 16kB buffer once and reusing it.
Since you're not working with a lot of data, it likely matters very little.

One last note: even with normal sockets, small read buffer sizes are likely only a matter of efficiency. You'd have to make them incredibly small to make those kernel calls take so long they cause congestion. The data transfer would have to be pretty fast too, the processor is (in most applications) quite a few orders of magnitude faster than your network link. So in general slower-speed cases, I'd air on the side of "just use recv with the sizes that make your code the most readable and simple".